# Subprocess not retaining all environment variables

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, tcsh

I have a tcsh shell script that sets up all the necessary environment including `PYTHONPATH`, which then run an executable at the end of it. I also have a python script that gets sent to the shell script as an input. So the following works perfectly fine when it is ran from Terminal:

`path to shell script` `path to python script`

Now, the problem occurs when I want to do the same thing from a **subprocess**. The python script fails to be ran since it cannot find many of the modules that's already supposed to be set via the shell script. And clearly, the `PYTHONPATH` ends up having many missing paths compared to the parent environment the subprocess was ran from or the shell script itself! It seems like the subprocess does not respect the environment the shell script sets up.

I've tried all sorts of things already but none help!

`cmd = [shell_script_path, py_script_path]
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, env=os.environ.copy())`

It makes no difference if env is not given either!

Any idea how to fix this?!

Comment: Have you tried saying `export PYTHONPATH` before you launch the Python script which calls Popen?  That will make child processes inherit that variable.

Comment: The environment the Popen is running from already contains all those paths! Or did you mean to export PYTHONPATH from shell? The shell script sets the environment itself.

Comment: No matter what I do, I keep getting ImportErrors and errors like this `'import site' failed; use -v for traceback`

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the subprocess inherits all the parent process environment and they are supposed to be ran under same environment, making the shell script to not setup any environment, fixed it.

This solves the environment being retained, but now the problem is, the process just hangs! (it does not happen when it is ran directly from shell)